# VueJs draggable sortable cancel adding element without cancel the drag preview

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working with [draggable and sortable with vueJS](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable), and i am trying to accomplish a thing, basicly i have 2 lists, the first one is a list with some sections like (table, paragraph ...) the second one are building blocks with this sections, but basicly the flow i need is, drag a element from list1 to list2, **but don't add the element** this is important because i need to open a modal first to set the properties of the element that will be added, and then add it to the futureIndex.

At the moment i have a solution where i can do almost what i need, i just need to understand how to cancel the addition of the element without struggling with the preview of the dragging, with preview i mean this:

[image]

i wanna see the adition of the elment at the middle.

So my first list i have done this:

```
<draggable v-model="sectionList" class="dragArea" @end="changeView()" :move="moveItem" :options="{group:{ name:'sections',pull:'clone',put:false }}">
    <div v-for="(section, index) in sectionList"  class="card card-color list-complete-item">
        <div class="card-block">
            <h4 class="card-title text-center">{{section.text}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</draggable>

methods: {
    addParagraph() {
        this.$set(this.paragraph, 'key', this.key);
        this.$set(this.paragraph, 'text', this.text);
        this.$set(this.paragraph, 'fontSize', this.fontSize);
        this.$store.commit("appendToDocument", this.paragraph)
    },
    changeView: function () {
        this.$store.commit("changeCurrentView", this.sectionList[this.dragedIndex].component);
        this.show();
    },
    show() {
        this.$modal.show('modalSection');
    },
    hide() {
        this.$modal.hide('modalSection');
    },
    currentIndex(evt) {
        console.log(evt.draggedContext.index);
    },
    moveItem(evt) { // future index of the modal that will be draged
        console.log(evt.draggedContext.futureIndex);
        this.dragedIndex = evt.draggedContext.index;
    }
},
```

the second list is not that important, as long as i can understand with this post, how to move the item without adding it and see the preview. i had added the return false at the end but with that i can't see the preview and i can't drag elements between the same list.

Any help with this?

Comment: Why not inserting the element on drop? You could use the clone props to fill the cloned element with placeholder values and open the model on the end event? I guess it will do the job, using move props and futureindex maybe problematic as there some know issues with futureindex value

Comment: i would like the solution friend, if you could detail it with a example maybe :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sortable` itself, the library `Vue.draggable` is based on, doesn't have a `drop` event handler ([link](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable/issues/264)), but this can get you started: https://jsfiddle.net/94z81596/10/. The key idea is making use of the `change` handler:

```
<draggable 
  id="list2" 
  class="dragArea" 
  :options="{group:'people'}" 
  @change="afterAdd"
  :list="gDocument">
...
</draggable>
```

The solution can be even simpler, you can just keep track of the `futureIndex` (and save it into the `placeholder`) and `return false` in `checkMove` and then manually insert the item yourself through `Vuex`. My current solution is already doing the almost same thing.

But I intended to keep the preview so the user can know where they're inserting the element. So I did some work to clean the list by doing this:

```
state.document = state.document.filter((item) => item.value);
```

Comment: so basicly i should let insert the first element to keep the preview, delete him show the modal and after that inserting the element? i will try my solution tommorrow, i remember i had a issue with futureIndex when i returned false with :move, the futureIndex where always wrong, but if i changed the return it was correct

Comment: It's simpler to do it this way if you want to keep the preview, and this can correct what is done by sortable after the drop, which we can't handle.

Comment: worked, i changed a little your implemantation, but the onchange method was great for this, thank you, i will acept it, just a thing, sometimes the futureIndex is a little buggy is it normal?

Comment: Usually when I use it I didn't notice anything wrong, but I'll have to take a deeper look at what's going on in the source code of `sortable` with `futureIndex` to answer your question.

Comment: i notice something when for example i have just 1 element and try to add below it, the futureIndex is 0 instead of 1, when i drag top and again bot it seems fine

Comment: It's kinda hard to guess what the root cause is I suggest you shoot me an email to continue the conversation and  take a deeper look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152444/discussion-between-filipe-costa-and-kevlai22).

Comment: can you give me your email so we can talk and solve the issue :/

Comment: @FilipeCosta kevlai22@uw.edu